# Update transfered Android App

Tags: google-play

I have android app in google play done by developer. Now app transferred to new developer and he did update in the application. Now we have to publish our updated app in google play. But we can not do that because of the keystore file.

I don't have previous release keystore file. So how we can publish our new update on google play in same application?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to update your app in Google Play Store without the keystore. If you have lost your keystore file then you can't update your application further more. You need to generate a new keystore file. For that you need to also upload your application with different package name with newly generated keystore certificate.

You might want to try to restore a deleted keystore file using various data recovery tools. Generally, the only advise that exists on keystores: always backup it.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html